# Error compiling `core/window.c` when attempting to install gnome in nixos

Tags: gnome, nixos, gnome-3

I run into an error when attempting to install [gnome](https://www.gnome.org/) on my nixos machine.

Here is what I've done:

1. Install NixOS. I followed the [installation instructions](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#ch-installation) of the [NixOS manual](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/) to install nixos on my machine from a usb drive. My machine used the "Legacy Boot (MBR)" option, rather than UEFI (GPT). Since my machine is 32-bit, I obtained the "Minimal installation CD, 32-bit Intel/AMD" to create my live-usb drive with from the "Getting NixOS 19.03" [download page](https://nixos.org/nixos/download.html). Installation was successful and I was able to login to a root shell on the machine to which this was installed.
2. Attempted to install the GNOME user interface. I edited my `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` to include the four lines listed under "Install Gnome" on [NixOS's GNOME page](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Gnome). After I did this and when I attempted to run `nixos-rebuild switch` is where I ran into this issue.

When I attempted to run `nixos-rebuild switch`, I got an error that appears to be an issue attempting to compile `core/window.c`; for that file the error message reads, "error: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions". The error is pasted below.

Any ideas on how I can deal with this to get gnome interface working on this machine?

```
Scanning dependencies of target templates_h
[ 29%] Generating ../../../share/templates/templates.h
[ 29%] Built target templates_h
[ 29%] Generating inkscape-version.cpp
revision is 5da689c313, 2019-01-14
  CC       core/frame.lo
  CC       core/meta-gesture-tracker.lo
  CC       core/meta-workspace-manager.lo
  CC       core/keybindings.lo
  CC       core/main.lo
  CC       core/place.lo
  CC       core/prefs.lo
  CC       core/startup-notification.lo
  CC       core/restart.lo
  CC       core/stack.lo
  CC       core/stack-tracker.lo
  CC       core/util.lo
  CC       core/window.lo
core/window.c: In function 'find_monitor_by_winsys_id':
core/window.c:3816:38: error: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Werror=sign-compare]
       if (logical_monitor->winsys_id == winsys_id)
                                      ^~
core/window.c: In function 'meta_window_move_resize_internal':
core/window.c:4062:32: error: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Werror=sign-compare]
       if (old_output_winsys_id != window->monitor->winsys_id &&
                                ^~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[4]: *** [Makefile:2844: core/window.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/build/mutter-3.30.2/src'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:3016: all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/build/mutter-3.30.2/src'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1856: all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/build/mutter-3.30.2/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:492: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/build/mutter-3.30.2'
make: *** [Makefile:422: all] Error 2
builder for '/nix/store/z91sx3gy787p6zfhji0j5i6kw7gpi1h7-mutter-3.30.2.drv' failed with exit code 2
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/wp4g905s768nxpcxjrb84laaph255dl6-gnome-control-center-3.30.3.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/clwxa761xd19d8qcxclnl6rigcmyb3l5-gnome-shell-3.30.2.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/y3zgqkhg2p8pm71qhwiimalq5yxvhlg7-gnome-tweaks-3.30.2.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
building '/nix/store/0wnhy9a7ifbp5vl96xanccjkir5fax3y-nixos-version.drv'...
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/vl8wrz15ixy1bzxqhmbcnxphi6x13h0p-gnome-session-3.30.1.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/2jmszmay6qlq69bgcpcl0czk8cjzihas-gnome-terminal-3.30.2.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/fzb9c8846g0my00g6nyijxd4ypjaxbj6-set-environment.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
building '/nix/store/d9ibna87vyfmvizrshwf1bilmmgsvhdn-strongswan-5.7.1.drv'...
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/l4a6vz4xi4w04m51yhzg2dirg5dw7130-system-path.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
building '/nix/store/d93srndgpxzlgpb6xfl9nv0zz2hlyjn8-systemd-user.pam.drv'...
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/9z4qacafhb98ijwxm6a2ckldmbazyxqs-nixos-system-nixos-19.03.172765.55df3fe5f3f.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
error: build of '/nix/store/9z4qacafhb98ijwxm6a2ckldmbazyxqs-nixos-system-nixos-19.03.172765.55df3fe5f3f.drv' failed
```

Comment: Well, local re-build from source may indicate that Gnome is not maintained by NixOS team, so you will probably run into different issues with it. This particular problem seems to be related with HARDENING which is enabled by default in NixOS. Try setting `NIX_HARDENING_ENABLE` environment variable to empty string. Note, that you need to modify gnome build environment, not the usual one.